# body_add_flextable returning error - no applicable method for 'docx_str'

Tags: r, flextable, officer

I have been trying to add a flextable created via rtable::FlexPivot into a word document using officer.

```
library(magrittr)
library(rtable)
library(officer)
library(flextable)

data = mtcars
data = group_by(data, vs, am, gear, carb)
data = summarise(data, avg = mean( mpg ), min = min( mpg ))

data$avg_col = ifelse( data$avg < 17, "red", "black" )
data$min_col = ifelse( data$min < 20, "gray", "purple" )

data$avg = sprintf( "%.3f", data$avg)
data$min = sprintf( "%.2f", data$min)


ft = FlexPivot( dataset = data, space = FALSE, columns.transpose = TRUE, 
            id = c("gear", "carb"), transpose = c("vs", "am"), 
            columns = c("avg", "min"), 
            color = c("avg"="avg_col", "min" = "min_col") )

my_doc <- read_docx() %>%
      body_add_par(value='Some text etc etc') %>%
      body_add_flextable(value=ft)
```

This returns an error message saying

> Error in UseMethod("docx_str") :    no applicable method for
>   'docx_str' applied to an object of class "FlexTable"

Any idea what might be causing this? I am using pandoc 2.1.3. pandoc_version() returns '2.1.3'.

Comment: I think that I have found the problem - the rtable FlexPivot function returns a 'FlexTable' object whereas the body_add_flextable takes a 'flextable' one. Are the objects returned from rtables similar to the ones returned by the flextable package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rtable` is designed to work with `ReporteRs` not with `officer`. Note that package ReporteRs will be removed from CRAN the 16th of July 2018 (due to incompatibility with java >=9), package `officer` is replacing `ReporteRs` and package `flextable` is replacing `ReporteRs::FlexTable` objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
newFT <- flextable(ft) #add this line 

#then this
my_doc <- read_docx() %>%
     body_add_par(value='Some text etc etc') %>%
     body_add_flextable(value=newFT)
```